# log-mel-spectrogram with specific size

Tags: python, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, speech-recognition

Extract log mel spectrogram
1) The length of the raw audio used is 8s long,
2) and then get the MelSpectrogram,
2) finally perform logarithmic operation to MelSpectrogram.
Return:
log_mel_spectrogram:

```
import librosa
import pathlib
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


def get_log_mel_spectrogram(path, n_fft, hop_length, n_mels):
    sr=16000 
    duration=8 
    n_mels=128 
    n_fft=2048
    hop_length=512
    y, sr = librosa.load(path,sr=sr)

    # Pad or segment the audio file
    if len(y) < duration*sr:
        y = librosa.util.fix_length(y, size=duration*sr)
    else:
        y_segments = librosa.util.frame(y, frame_length=duration*sr, hop_length=duration*sr, axis=0)
        y = y_segments[:, 0]

    # Compute the log Mel spectrogram
    S = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=y, sr=sr, n_fft=n_fft, hop_length=hop_length, n_mels=n_mels)

    # Convert to log scale (dB)
    log_mel_spectrogram = librosa.power_to_db(S, ref=np.max)
    log_mel_spectrogram = log_mel_spectrogram.reshape((-1,))

    return log_mel_spectrogram
```

it should return (128x251) in 1D array.
Returns:
train_data_x, train_data_y:
The emotion data and label of train data, which account for 80% in all.
validation_data_x, validation_data_y:
The emotion data and label of validation data, which account for 80% in train data.
test_data_x, test_data_y:
The emotion data and label of test data, which account for 20% in all.

```
def load_data(path):
 
    train_data_x = []
    train_data_y = []
    validation_data_x = []
    validation_data_y = []
    test_data_x = []
    test_data_y = []

    dataset_dict = classify_files(path)

    '''Split data set'''
    emotion_label_list = dataset_dict['file_dict'].keys()
    for emotion_label in emotion_label_list:
        x = dataset_dict['file_dict'][emotion_label]['all_data']
        count = dataset_dict['file_dict'][emotion_label]['count']
        y = np.full(count, dataset_dict['file_dict'][emotion_label]['represent'])

        x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, train_size=0.8)

        x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(x_train, y_train, train_size=0.8)

        train_data_x = np.append(train_data_x, x_train)
        train_data_y = np.append(train_data_y, y_train)

        validation_data_x = np.append(validation_data_x, x_val)
        validation_data_y = np.append(validation_data_y, y_val)

        test_data_x = np.append(test_data_x, x_test)
        test_data_y = np.append(test_data_y, y_test)

    '''Reshape all data'''
    train_data_x = np.array(train_data_x).reshape(-1, 128, 251, 1)
    train_data_y = np.array(train_data_y)
    validation_data_x = np.array(validation_data_x).reshape(-1, 128, 251, 1)
    validation_data_y = np.array(validation_data_y)
    test_data_x = np.array(test_data_x).reshape(-1, 128, 251, 1)
    test_data_y = np.array(test_data_y)

    return train_data_x, train_data_y, validation_data_x, validation_data_y, test_data_x, test_data_y
```

but now i am getting an error saying

```
<ipython-input-21-932cc5bcfb40> in load_data(path)
    142 
    143     '''Reshape all data'''
--> 144     train_data_x = np.array(train_data_x).reshape(-1, 128, 251, 1)
    145     train_data_y = np.array(train_data_y)
    146     validation_data_x = np.array(validation_data_x).reshape(-1, 128, 251, 1)

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 9542055 into shape (128,251,1)
```

Is the return of get log mel spectrogram function is not of (128, 251) reshaped in 1D array? How to resolve the Error.I am working with EmoDB dataset having 535 audio.

Comment: Will change in dataset size help to remove the error ? if so what should be the size of dataset.

Comment: Please do not use the comments space to add stuff - edit & update your question instead.